# Some problems about copy and paste in the vba code

Tags: excel, vba

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2   1   005
2   2   4   2   005
3   3   6   3   005
4   4   8   4   005
5   5   10  5   005
```

I would like to copy the data from the Worksheets("A") to the Worksheets("B"), the column C and column D are the text format.

There are problems that all data are the value format if I used either following codes, like the result as follow:

```
Worksheets("B").Range("A1:D5").Value = Worksheets("A").Range("A1:D5").Value
```

Or

```
Worksheets("A").Activate
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 4)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("B").Cells(1, 1)
```

-

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2   1   5
2   2   4   2   5
3   3   6   3   5
4   4   8   4   5
5   5   10  5   5
```

If I used the below code that can obtain the result I want. I would like to ask have any other faster ways to achieve the wanted result?

```
Worksheets("A").Activate
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5, 4)).Copy
Worksheets("B").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The below result is I wanted in Worksheets("B").

```
    A   B   C   D
1   1   2   1   005
2   2   4   2   005
3   3   6   3   005
4   4   8   4   005
5   5   10  5   005
```

The another question is why the below code get error?

```
Worksheets("B").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5,4)).Value = Worksheets("A").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5,4)).Value
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's the best solution to copy and paste. As you have figured out, you can't just simple copy the values, because the format is different. With `PasteSpecial` you can first paste the format and then the values:

```
With Worksheets("A")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(5, 4)).Copy
End With
With Worksheets("B").
    .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With
```

The other question why you get an error:

You need to add the Worksheet before your Cells in the Range:

```
Worksheets("B").Range(Worksheets("B").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("B").Cells(5, 4)).Value = Worksheets("A").Range(Worksheets("A").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("A").Cells(5, 4)).Value
```

Comment: Oh. You solve the second questions for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you have worksheet insider the range, do you still need worksheet out front?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, there is no faster way of doing this than using pastespecial with `xlPasteValues`.

Another way of doing it is to change the format of the destination cells to text and then do a normal copy. Vba doesn't do nothing more, than what the user can do manually in this case. Even if you do it manually, you can't just copy your data to another sheet with different format and expect to stay the same. You have to use **pastespecial --> paste values only**.

[image: Paste as Values]

The same applies to Vba.

For the second part of your question,

```
Worksheets("B").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5,4)).Value = _
Worksheets("A").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(5,4)).Value
```

your problem is with the range function. Cells(1,1) returns the value of Cell(1,1) and not the address. Range needs the cell address to work, and that causes trouble.

[image: Cells function]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see.